# Understanding a simple proof by contradiction

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I have a proof by contradiction to a simple problem but I have an issue understanding one aspect of it. I labeled it in the picture. Any insight would be helpful. Thank you for the time. [image]

Comment: You probably had the set $B\setminus C$ defined as the set of the elements that: (1) belong to $B$ and (2) don't belong to $C$. The two sentences before the one you question assert that $a$ satisfies both (1) and (2). For other definitions of $B\setminus C$ the arguments would be slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a\in A$, $a\in B$. And now, since $a\notin C$, $a\in B\setminus C$.

Comment: Thank you my friend, its so obvious now. I think I need to sleep. After the 10min cool down I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

$B \setminus C$ is the set of all elements in $B$ and not in $C$. We have that $a \in B$. Supposing $a \notin C$ means that $a \in B \setminus C$ by the definition of $B \setminus C$, but this contradicts the hypothesis that $a \notin B \setminus C$. Therefore $a$ must be in $C$.